# No 'prompt' module

Tags: python, eclipse, prompt

So, not completely new to programming but just starting with Python and Eclipse.  Entered "import prompt" and got an error message.  Opened Python in the command prompt (windows 10), entered "import prompt" and was told there's no module named 'prompt'.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: There is no module named `prompt` in the Python standard library. Why do you want to import it? What's the goal you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: `input()` doesn't work?

Comment: Hi.  Well I wondered about that.  I was just following a tutorial, trying to get started, just following directions.  So far everything else seems to be working ok so I guess I won't worry too much about it.  Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Would anyone know a really good, up-to-date tutorial for learning Python and Eclipse?  I've been looking but at this point I don't know enough to really tell a good one from a bad one.  Thanks!